# How to send a personal message (PM) in Yahoo Messenger with C#?

Tags: c#, yahoo-messenger

How do I send a [personal message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_message) (PM) to a Yahoo user in [Yahoo Messenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger) using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Yahoo Messenger SDK](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. sniff the packet. yahoo packet
2. create function for your packet
3. create socket class to send & revise
4. get cookies from login.yahoo.com by send your username & password
5. get data and pick Y&T cookie
6. send your Y&T with your id to login yahoo
7. revise data ...